# How to get a list of CLs submitted since a specific CL?

Tags: perforce

I have a CL number, and I want the CL number for all change lists submitted since that change list.  Is there a perforce command to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`p4 changes //... @yourchangelistnumber,@now` make sure you limit to a folder deeper then //... as that command can take a while if you do it against the entire depot.

Comment: Thanks!  How does this work for a specific workspace/client spec, rather than a depot folder?

Comment: You can limit the results to changelists submitted by a specific clientspec/workspace using the -c flag, like this: `p4 changes -c theclientspec //...@thechangelist,@now`.

Comment: Hmm.. doesn't seem to be working for me.  Returns nothing when it should be returning ~10 cls.  I will investigate further!

Comment: The proper command for that would be `p4 changes //theclient/...@changelist,@now`.  You can treat clients as depots.  Here is another tip while we are on the topic, you can find out the current changelist of a client by running `p4 changes -m1 @theclient`.